# Why I have to write the namespace to access to this extension method?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have a project that has class to implement extension methods for some type. For example I have this class for ObservableCollection:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;


namespace MyProject.Collections.Utils
{
    public static class ObservableCollection
    {
        public static void RemoveAll<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection, Func<T, bool> condition)
        {
            for (int i = collection.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (condition(collection[i]))
                {
                    collection.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }//RemoveAll
    }
}
```

With this class, in my main project I can use this library with the using:

```
using MyProject.Collections.Utils
```

And when I want to use the extension methods I can do:

```
ObservableCollection<MyType> myOC = new ObservableCollection<MyType>();
myOC.RemoveAll(x=>x.MyProperty == "123");
```

So I have access to my extension method.

However, I have another class for Decimal, is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace MyProject.Decimal.Utils
{
    public static class Decimal
    {
        public static decimal? Parse(this string paramString)
        {
            try
            {
                myCode
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }//Parse
    }
}
```

But in this case, although in my main prject I import the class:

```
using MyProject.Decimal.Utils;
```

If I do this:

```
decimal? myDecimalParsed= Decimal.Utils.Decimal.Parse("123");
```

Why in this case I can't do this?:

```
decimal? myDecimalParsed= decimal.Parse("123");
```

thank so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two problems:

- You can't use extension methods as if they were *static* methods of the extended type
- `System.Decimal` already *has* a `Parse` method, and the compiler always looks for "real" methods before extension methods.

In fact, you *can* write

```
decimal? miTiempoEstimadoParseado = decimal.Parse("123");
```

... but that will just call the normal method and then convert the `decimal` to `decimal?` implicitly in the normal way.

Note that you're not really using your method as an extension method at the moment anyway - to do so you'd write something like:

```
decimal? miTiempoEstimadoParseado = "123".Parse();
```

... but personally I'd view that as pretty ugly, partly as the method name doesn't indicate the target type at all, and partly because by convention `Parse` methods throw an exception instead of returning a null value on failure. You probably want to come up with a different name.

Comment: Maybe `ParseOrDefault` :D